# Create combinations from two lists based on variable number of items from first list

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I've been struggling with this one for a bit, so I thought I would reach out!

So I have two lists of index locations that I need to generate combinations from.  (Originally I had one list, and attempted to use itertools.product and itertools.combinations, but the real data creates memory errors due to size.)

So originally: (think x,y coordinates)

```
coords = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [6, 10], [6, 11], [6, 12], [6, 13], [6, 14], [6, 15], [6, 16], [6, 17], [6, 18], [6, 19], [6, 20], [6, 21], [6, 22], [6, 23], [6, 24], [6, 25], [6, 26], [6,
27], [6, 28], [6, 29], [7, 0], [7, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3]]

#the coords get transformed into this:
#each "x" element contains the "y" sub elements

coord_list = [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [0, 1, 2, 3]]

output = list(itertools.product(*coord))
```

This works until I get upwards of 20 levels in my index (I've only shown 7 levels of index in the example)

So I thought that I could limit the number of combinations being generated by splitting the list into the important characteristics that interest me, and limiting how many are used at a time.

I have a variable (cutoff) that defines how many items to pull from the first list (neg_list).
A new list needs to be populated with those items from the neg_list, and then with elements from the other list (pos_list).

The catch is that you can only use one item from each index level, and I need the resulting lists to reuse items from the first list only if absolutely necessary. (Maybe by adding a counter to the elements?) - The goal is to use every element at least once, but distribute the times elements at a particular index level are reused as much as possible.  ....Maybe itertools.takewhile() would be handy for this?

```
cutoff = 2
depth = 7  #The number of unique items in the first index position

pos_list = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [6, 2], [7, 1]]
neg_list = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 9], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 2], [4, 0], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [5, 0], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 0], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [6, 10], [6, 11], [6, 12], [6, 13], [6, 14], [6, 15], [6, 16], [6, 17], [6, 18], [6, 19], [6, 20], [6, 21], [6, 22], [6, 23], [6, 24], [6, 25], [6, 26], [6, 27], [6, 28], [6, 29], [7, 0], [7, 2], [7, 3]]

pseudo code:
add use_count to each element of neg_list and pos_list
get cutoff number of elements randomly from neg_list with unique first index number by choosing lowest use_count until all items have a use_count > 0
populate remaining elements up to depth number with elements from pos_list with unique first index number and lowest use_count
increment use_count on used elements in neg_list and pos_list

pseudo output:
an array or list of lists with all the combinations generated
cutoff 2 partial example: (the ^^^ indicate where the neg_list "seeds" are)

[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1]]
  ^^^^                    ^^^^
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 18], [7, 1]]
          ^^^^                                    ^^^^^


pos_list would then maybe look like:
[[[0, 1],1], [[1, 1],1], [1, 7], [1, 8], [[2, 0],2], [[3, 1],1], [[4, 1],2] [[5, 1],2], [[6, 1],1], [[6, 2],0], [[7, 1],2]]

neg list would look similar, with counts next to the elements that have been used
```

The cutoff is the only variable that can change. So a cutoff of 1, would generate 54 sets I think. A cutoff of two would generate a bunch of combinations while maximizing the variability of the elements used.

Thoughts? I'm not sure where to go with this one.

Comment: where do you take `use_count` from?

Comment: tuples may be better than lists here because they use less memory

Comment: you're saying "get cutoff number of elements randomly from `neg_list`" but above you're saying "I have a variable that defines how many items to pull from the **first** list". So which one is it? Please, add more details. Your question is hard to understand. Have you tried writing python code? Please provide what you have tried

Comment: My thought on use_count was that would eb a way i could track how many times each element has been used (to avoid using the same elements over and over when possible)

Comment: either I don't understand something, or the first sublist in your example is wrong cause it shows two elements from the same level of `pos_list` (`[6,1]` and `[6,2]`)

Comment: These are pointers to locations of data. 6,1 and 6,2 are both pos values, but you can only use one of them in the output lists. The goal would be to use them as equally as possible as the outputs are generated

Comment: Crap, that was unintended. Fixed

Comment: The actual output would be a list of lists, or whatever data structure is best that would hold all the combinations. I just provided two examples of the individual lists that would be inside the list of lists.

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to include as much of information and make examples as full as possible?

Comment: I wish I could! Basically I am trying to limit the number of combinations being created, because when my index's get above 20, the exponential growth is too much. (I only provided index levels up to 7 in this example)

Comment: first of all, what combinations are you talking about?

Comment: The output combinations. I need to generate all combinations of the two lists, utilizing a define number of items from one list. Each index level can't be repeated, and the reuse of elements needs to be minimized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247231/discussion-between-vladimir-fokow-and-steve).

Comment: No, I just realized I have the wrong data in that product example.  I'll break out a working dat chunk.   And for wrapping it in list(), that's just so I can see the result instead of the generator. In the working code it isn't wrapped

Comment: Just responded!

Comment: posted some answers/examples

Comment: added the solution that matches all given examples

Comment: It would be good if you rewrote your question (included all examples and a clear explanation of the algorithm) so that other people could find it useful in the future (without needing to read all our discussion in chat)

Comment: I will sit down and create a better version of the question. It was definitely tricky, and your solution works great.  I did just message you, and add a comment to your solution, because I forgot to state that it needs to be able to include a "clean" set of results as well corresponding to a cutoff of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parameters:**

```py
good_coords = [(0,0), (1,0)] 
bad_coords = [(0,1), (1,1), (1,2)] 
cutoff = 2
```

#### The `x`-indices of your data must be SORTED.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations, cycle

# 'xs' stands for 'x-es', plural of 'x'
xs = sorted(list(set(pair[0] for pair in good_coords)
                 .union(set(pair[0] for pair in bad_coords))))

# Define 2 dictionaries. In each one:
# - keys are unique values of `x`, 
# - values are lists of `y` corresponding to that `x`. 
# All good pairs are in `pairs_good`, and all bad ones - in `pairs_bad`:
pairs_good = defaultdict(list, {x:[] for x in xs})
pairs_bad = defaultdict(list, {x:[] for x in xs})
for x, y in good_coords:
    pairs_good[x].append(y)
for x, y in bad_coords:  
    pairs_bad[x].append(y)

# Define a dictionary where:
# Keys will be all integers from 0 to `cutoff`: `n_bad`.
# Values will be lists containing other lists: sequences of `y` -
# all the results corresponding to this `n_bad`:
sequences_for_each_n_bad = {}

# for `n_bad == 0`:
chosen_ys = [cycle(ys) for ys in pairs_good.values()]
sequences = []
maxlen = max(len(pairs) for pairs in pairs_good.values())
seq_iterator = zip(*chosen_ys)
while maxlen > 0:
    sequences.append(next(seq_iterator))
    maxlen -= 1
sequences_for_each_n_bad[0] = sequences

# for all other `n_bad`: >0:
for n_bad in range(1, cutoff + 1):
    sequences = []
    # `good_ys` and `bad_ys` are cyclic infinite iterators
    all_good_ys = [cycle(ys) for ys in pairs_good.values()]
    all_bad_ys = [cycle(ys) for ys in pairs_bad.values()] 
    
    # Go through all the possibilities of bad index locations:
    for bad_ind_locs in combinations(range(len(xs)), n_bad):
        maxlen = max(len(pairs_bad[xs[i]]) for i in bad_ind_locs)
        # Create a list of the CHOSEN cyclic iterators of `y`s -
        # each of them good or bad, depending on `bad_ind_locs`:
        chosen_ys = [bad_ys if idx in bad_ind_locs else good_ys
                     for idx, (good_ys, bad_ys) 
                     in enumerate(zip(all_good_ys, all_bad_ys))]
        # Iterate over all elements of all rows (in parallel),
        # until the last element of the longest bad row is reached:
        seq_iterator = zip(*chosen_ys)
        while maxlen > 0:
            sequences.append(next(seq_iterator))
            maxlen -= 1
    
    sequences_for_each_n_bad[n_bad] = sequences
```

**Result for the inputs above:**

```py
sequences_for_each_n_bad
```

```py
{0: [(0, 0)], 1: [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], 2: [(1, 1), (1, 2)]}
```

The keys of the dictionary `sequences_for_each_n_bad`  are `n_bads` (then number of bad elements in a sequence). The values are all chosen sequences of `y`s, for this number of bad elements.

Note that `x` always has the same values in the same positions (0, 1, 2) -- so it is not necessary to store them in the pairs. I am storing them in a list `xs` (x-ses) (assuming that your `x`s are in the ascending order).

If you would like ***to convert the output into your format***, you could use:

```py
aslist = [[list(zip(xs, sequence)) for sequence in sequences]
           for n_bad, sequences 
           in sequences_for_each_n_bad.items()]
[sublist for n_bad_list in aslist
         for sublist in n_bad_list]
```

```py
[[(0, 0), (1, 0)],
 [(0, 1), (1, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (1, 1)],
 [(0, 0), (1, 2)],
 [(0, 1), (1, 1)],
 [(0, 1), (1, 2)]]
```

---

#### Testing other examples:

1. 

```py
good_coords = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)] 
bad_coords = [(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2)] 
cutoff = 2
```

```py
{0: [(0, 0, 0)],
 1: [(1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)],
 2: [(1, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (1, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 2)]}
```

2. 

```py
good_coords = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0),(3,3)] 
bad_coords = [(0,1), (1,1),(1,2), (2,1),(2,2),(2,3), (3,1),(3,2)]
cutoff = 2
```

```py
{0: [(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 3)],
 1: [(1, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 1, 0, 3),
  (0, 2, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 1, 3),
  (0, 0, 2, 0),
  (0, 0, 3, 3),
  (0, 0, 0, 1),
  (0, 0, 0, 2)],
 2: [(1, 1, 0, 0),
  (1, 2, 0, 3),
  (1, 0, 1, 0),
  (1, 0, 2, 3),
  (1, 0, 3, 0),
  (1, 0, 0, 1),
  (1, 0, 0, 2),
  (0, 1, 1, 3),
  (0, 2, 2, 0),
  (0, 1, 3, 3),
  (0, 2, 0, 1),
  (0, 1, 0, 2),
  (0, 0, 1, 1),
  (0, 0, 2, 2),
  (0, 0, 3, 1)]}
```

Comment: I think this does exactly what I was hoping. I was just able to run some tests on it, and with some minor tweaks it worked for me!  And then I had the glaring realization I left out one requirement.  That the result also include a pure set of "good" combinations equivalent to the cutoff = 0  (no selections from the bad list)

Comment: @Steve, done. Consider hiring someone on freelance next time